# Jsoup selector not returning results

Tags: java, android, jsoup

My Java code using the Jsoup selector is returning null (Toast is showing '0') when running the following:

```
String vidLink = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=adele+hello";
Document searchResultsPage = pageLoadLooper(vidLink, 1);
Elements testElems = searchResultsPage.select("div.yt-lockup.yt-lockup-tile.yt-lockup-video.clearfix");

Integer Size = (Integer) testElems.size();
Toast.makeText(context, Size.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When I test out the same selector here, using the HTML from "View Source" of "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=adele+hello": http://try.jsoup.org/, it returns exactly as expected.

Here is the code for the pageLoadLooper as well:

```
public Document pageLoadLooper(String url, int counter) {
    int maxAttempts = 10000;
    int millisTimeout = 30000;
    Document page = null;
    try {
        page = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(millisTimeout).maxBodySize(0).get(); //max body size = no limit
        return page;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        counter++;
        if (counter < maxAttempts) {
            return pageLoadLooper(url, counter);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("page request exceeded limit");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as to why this is returning null!!

Comment: Works for me, using jsoup-1.8.3. `Size` is *19*. Which version are you using?

Comment: Yup, using the same version as you.  I tried moving everything into onCreate in MainActivity as well to check, but no dice.  No idea what's going on.  I also toasted the "searchResultsPage.html()" and that works fine.

Comment: is `pageLoadLooper` in a separated thread? Otherwise Android will complain for using network on main thread

Comment: It is in the UI thread, however I added this within the onCreate method to temporarily get around it:
    
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);